# Filter by close reason in reopen votes review queue is not working

Tags: bug, review-queues, close-reasons, filtering

Screenshot of my filter:

[image]

As you can see, "It was initially closed as **duplicate**"

Why did I get this review item ([here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22984397))? It is an audit?

Update: it wasn't an audit. I made a decision and there was no popup like "Congratulations!" or "STOP!". So, it can be really a bug.

Comment: The question was closed as "off-topic" first, then edited (which kicked it into the review queue), then later reopened and closed as duplicate. I wonder if the reopen by a mod should have removed the question from the reopen review queue. It seems like it didn't, that is why you still see it, because it was closed as "off-topic" when it landed in the queue, but it just tells you the new close reason. If it got removed from the queue and later added again due to edits after being closed as "duplicate", then I have no idea how this could appear in your queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Tom noted in the comments, the question *was* previously closed as off-topic... Which is where the bug comes in. This is how the filter is applied for the reopen queue:

```
select PostId
from   PostHistory
where  PostHistoryTypeId = 10 -- closed
       and Comment in @closeReasonFilter
```

That just checks that the question was closed for one of the reasons specified - it doesn't check that the question is *currently* closed for one of the reasons specified.

The fix here is probably to constrain those PostHistory entries to those matching the ClosedDate of the posts being reviewed.